# Qr code on non flat surface projection software

Tags: image, image-processing

I need to project a qr code on a bottle of wine, so i need a sort a anamorphic distortion of the printed qr code to see the qr code perfectly square from the camera. Is there a software that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguous: do you need to (a) expand a QR code along the horizontal direction so that it will look square when seen from a camera, or (b) squeeze it so it looks as if it had been glued onto the bottle?

Probably the easiest way to do (b) is to use any 3d modeling package (e.g. Blender, 3D Studio Max, Maya, ...), building a cylinder and texture-mapping the image of the QR code onto it.

Or you can do both (a) and (b) in Matlab, which allows you to arbitrarily remap any matrix through a 2d->2d function (and in this case it's really 1d, since there's no distortion along the vertical). The distorted coordinate s on the QR code and its orthographic projection x are related as (x/R) = sin(s/R), where R is the radius of the cylinder.

Comment: Well, easy then: the squeeze due to the curvature is x/s in my formula above (it's the ratio of a cord to the segment of circumference it subtends). Remap the image using its inverse and you're done.